# Flexbox center and bottom right item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the following result using flexbox:
[image: Flexbox demo]

I tried the with the following html but I can't get it to work.

```
<div class=" flex-center">
    <div class="flex-item-center">
        <p>
            Some text in box A
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-bottom">
        <p>Some text in box B....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-item-center {
  align-self: center;
}

.flex-item-bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

How can I make it look like the image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've made a posible solution.

```css
.flex-center {
  background-color: #739FD0;
  color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
}
.flex-center-bottom {
  background-color: #739FD0;
  color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-item-center {
  border: solid 2px #4675AA;
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: center;
}
.flex-item-bottom {
  border: solid 2px #4675AA;
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-center">
  <div class="flex-item-center">
    <p>DROP FILES HERE</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-center-bottom">
  <div class="flex-item-center">
    <p>Hint: You can also drop files in the all files page</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 2017:** Tested in Google Chrome Versión 62.0.3202.89 (Build oficial) (32 bits).

```css
.flex-center,
.flex-center-bottom {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #739FD0;
  color: #000000;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-center {
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-center-bottom {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-item-center {
  border: solid 2px #4675AA;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1px;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-center">
  <div class="flex-item-center">
    <p>Some text in box A</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-center-bottom">
  <div class="flex-item-center">
    <p>Some text in box B...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The markup does not use the flex-item-bottom class and flex-item-center does nothing meaningful.

Comment: I just made the proper changes to use the minimum code. Thank you @DanielRuf for the observation.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/q12bh4se/6/

```
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  /* Safari 7.0+ */
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#main div {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-item-center {
  margin-left: 40%;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  /* Safari 7.0+ */
  align-self: center;
}

.flex-item-bottom {
  border-style: solid;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: I think you used the wrong jsfiddle. Because that one is about keyframes and animation?

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 4.x you can use the [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">center center</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end h-100">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-end">right bottom</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

*Since I received a couple downvotes I believe a review is in order.*
To me the above answer is still valid, however I understand it's not clear it requires some height.

How this `height` is achieved doesn't really matter. Either you set it fixed in CSS on a wrapper or for the code snippet's sake we set the document's height to make it responsive.

If the "center content" takes up the space in height, the "bottom content" can be positioned absolute, so it doesn't add height. All what's left is to make sure it covers the full width and positions from the `bottom`.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; } /* can be anything that generates height */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">center center</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end position-absolute w-100 fixed-bottom">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-end">right bottom</div>
</div>
```

So functionality wise, there's no additional CSS required in Bootstrap.

**[Documentation justify content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content)**
**[Documentation position](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#fixed-bottom)**

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```css
#main-wrapper {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.x-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.y-center {
  flex: 1;
}

.x-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.y-bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.small-div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div class="x-center y-center small-div">Center center</div>
  <div class="x-right y-bottom small-div">Bottom Right</div>
</div>
```

Notes:

The align-self won't work for IE10 or below.
Anybody know how to make the center div a bit more to the left without position relativing it? Thanks