# make horizontal and vertical center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div and inside that div, I have the text and one card and I have to make them vertical and horizontally centre similar to the image below. Thanks in advance.

```css
.percentile-card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.percentile-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <h2 style="font-size: 3em;">Where Do i Stand Overall ?</h2>
  <div class="percentile-card text-center">
    <h3>You did better Than</h3>
    <h3><b>60%</b></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Also possible with [utility classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402001/flexbox-center-and-bottom-right-item/51058417#51058417)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watch all answers and I don't think, those answers are valid. So, I posted an answer.

```css
.root_class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .root_class {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.text {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #bbb;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.percentile-card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.percentile-card p {
  margin: 0;
}

.percentile-card p:first-child {
  color: #bbb;
}

.percentile-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="border root_class">
  <p class="text">Where Do i Stand Overall ?</p>
  <div class="percentile-card text-center">
    <p>You did better Than</p>
    <p><b>60%</b></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: its not responsive

Comment: Oh, someone downvoted my answer without telling me the reason 

Answer (score 1):

In order to *centre* that in the middle of the page you can remove the `float` property from `percentile-card` and replace it with a *centred* margin.

For vertical alignment you can use view height.

This [w3 link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_margin_auto) might be useful in highlighting margins. Along with [these](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) demos.

As for view height, if you do not want it set based on a constraint from the preceding element, you may want to consider [positions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .percentile-card{
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      width: 800px;
      height: 30%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding:10px;
    }

    .percentile-card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .border{
        margin-top: 40vh;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="border">
    <div class="percentile-card" style="display: flex;">
        <div style="flex-basis: 70%">
            <h2 style="font-size: 3em;">Where do I stand overall ?</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="percentile-card" style="flex-basis: 30%">
            <h3 >You did better Than</h3>
            <h3><b>60%</b></h3>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

For the border with card inside variant:

Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .percentile-card{
          box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          transition: 0.3s;
          width: 800px;
          height: 30%;
          
        }

        .percentile-card:hover {
          box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .border{
            margin-top: 40vh;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="border">
        <div class="" style="display: flex; border:1px solid black;margin: 0 auto; padding:10px;width: 800px">
            <div style="flex-basis: 70%">
                <h2 style="font-size: 3em;">Where do I stand overall ?</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="percentile-card" style="flex-basis: 30%">
                <h3 >You did better Than</h3>
                <h3><b>60%</b></h3>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not working. the card is coming below the text.

Comment: No like I want card to be beside that text and whole thing should be centred both text and card. Please check the image I have provided

Comment: @Equinox only put snippet in your answer, don't repeat your code and snippet

Answer (score 0):

[Centering Things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

Best place to understand and apply the centering css per your use case.

As per your code above, you can add css in your `border` class to be:

```
.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center
}
```

Below is working snippet:

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center
}
.percentile-card{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.percentile-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
      <div class="border">
        <h2 style="font-size: 3em;">Where Do i Stand Overall ?</h2>
        <div class="percentile-card text-center">
          <h3>You did better Than</h3>
          <h3><b>60%</b></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i fix it....

```css
.percentile-card{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.percentile-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.Center{
position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
  <div class="border">
        <h2 style="font-size: 3em;">Where Do i Stand Overall ?</h2>
        <div class="percentile-card text-center Center">
          <h3>You did better Than</h3>
          <h3><b>60%</b></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
```