# Horizontally center top, middle, bottom divs into container. Using Bootstrap 4 classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can not figure out how to horizontally center the div elements.

```
.d-flex.flex-row.justify-content-center
    div.align-self-start
        p Top

    div.align-self-center
        p Middle

    div.align-self-end
        p Bottom
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that includes information (like the html and css for these divs) needed to create the example provided.

Comment: plausible duplicate can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402001/flexbox-center-and-bottom-right-item/51058417#51058417)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to address your case specifically, as you have been incredibly vague in your question and the example provided. That being said, [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hr97duae/2/) shows one way that you can horizontally center div elements based on their class within a flex container.

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="centered">Top</div>
  <div class="centered">Mid</div>
  <div class="centered">Bot</div>
</div>
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div.centered {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #33ee33;
  align-self: center;
}
```